# Split a Image Into Tiles

Tags: windows-xp, images, processing

I have an image that is too large for what I am trying to do with it (I need images under 1 mega pixel). Is there an easy way to split it into several smaller images? My image is 2646x3058. I would like to split it into 9 images that are all the same size. I realize that I could do this manually for this image, but I would like to find an automatic way to do this as this will be a reoccurring problem for me.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Windows XP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [TileMage Image Splitter](http://tilemage.50webs.com/)

> TileMage Image Splitter is a freeware
>   program designed to offer a simple
>   solution for those who seek to slice a
>   single image into a given number of
>   columns and rows.

it requires the .NET framework but also runs under Mono.

Answer (score 9):

Install [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), its free and available for windows and unix.
Then:

```
$ convert -crop 1000x1000 <yourfilename.jpg> <base_of_outputfilenames.jpg>
```

This will give you files that are <= 1M pixel, so the ones on the border might be smaller than the other ones. If you want them to be all of the same size you need to calculate the size in advance, or use something like:

```
$ convert -crop 25%x25% <yourfilename.jpg> <base_of_outputfilenames.jpg>
```

But this might lead to some tiles that are only one or two pixels wide if the width is not divisible by 4..

Answer (score 2):

You can use this online simple tool to split your images - http://imagesplitter.net 
It allows to process images weight up to 20MB.

Comment: You have to upload your image to the website and their privacy policy doesn't mention them deleting the images.